# Verify if an input checkbox is checked in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table in my HTML and one of the cells in every row there is a **input check box**.

Now I am trying to check **if the checkbox is selected or not** and below is what I have tried.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="just_a_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Select</th>
          <th scope="col">IP Addr</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of instances">
          <td><input type="checkbox" (click)='onSelect()'></td>
          <td>{{data["IP"]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**TS:**

```
onSelect() {
    // We get the table data from the html and find if the checkbox is active.
    // The rows of the tables can be accessed by "rows" object and cells can be accessed using "cells" object.
    this.table_data = document.getElementById("just_a_table")

        for (var i=1, row; row = this.table_data.rows[i]){
          for (var j=0, cell; cell = row.cells[j]){
            if (<HTMLInputElement>cell[1].checked){
              console.log("It is checked")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing it this, way because I do not want to get the input element with it's ID and see if it checked.

Any help/directions here would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean AngularJS (i.e. angular v1), or just Angular (i.e. v2 +)?

Comment: You mention AngularJs (1.x) in the question but you have shown Angular (2.x+) code.  Also, you mention javascript, but show typescript code.

Comment: @user184994, my bad, it is v2+. I will now remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: Dont worry, looks like @Claies has already done it, though you may want to amend the title. Regarding the checkboxes: why not just use `ngModel` bindings?

Comment: Why do not want to get the input element with it's ID and see if it checked? That's preferred way! Instances must be array of objects so just have one property checked in each of those objects & use it as a model variable for those input checkbox fields

Comment: toggle value of indices of records to an array on click, you will have your solution, array will any time hold all indices which have checkbox checked.

Comment: @user184994, I tried it. I want to loop through the entire table and form and array based on the checkbox status. The ngModel would work if it is just one input checkbox, I am really not sure if it would work on a loop.

The cell[0] is a input checkbox and the cell[1] is a string. If the input is checked, I take the cell[1] and push it to an array. Is there a way to do this via ngModel? Just a direction, I am happy to research on this :)

Comment: You can either add it as a property to `data`, or instead create a new array (called `checks` for example), change your `*ngFor` to include the index (`*ngFor="let data of instances, i = index`), and then bind to your array with `[(ngModel)]="checks[i]"`

Comment: @user184994, my apologies. Where are we verifying the checkbox in this case?

Comment: Check my updated answer, I was not taking  into account that your result could be an array of values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML**

```
 <table class="table table-hover" id="just_a_table">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th scope="col">Select</th>
               <th scope="col">IP Addr</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let data of instances">
               <td><input type="checkbox" (change)='onSelect($event)'></td>
               <td>{{data["IP"]}}</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
```

You need to check `event.target.checked` to solve this issue. This is how you can achieve that:

**TS**

```
onSelect(event) {
     if ( event.target.checked ) {
        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

1. You should be using (change) instead of (click) because it's better
   practice
2. Stop thinking on JS. You are now using Typescript and
       Angular. These frameworks exist because vanilla JS sucks so no need
       to keep writing vanilla js when you are using this awesome
       libraries/frameworks

Answer (score 2):

First off I would use the Angular (click) event binding, I would also change your ngFor loop to this:

`<tr *ngFor="let data of instances; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">`

now we can use the index to know which checkbox is checked.

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="just_a_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Select</th>
          <th scope="col">IP Addr</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of instances; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
          <td><input type="checkbox" value="false" (click)='onSelect($event, i)'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would then populate an array with false values for the length of instance. This is only if you need to know which one's are ticked, there are other methods to do this but this one comes to mind.

```
constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.instances.length; i++) {
        this.resultArray.push(false);
    }
}
```

I would then use event.target.checked to get the checked value of the clicked on checkbox and, based on the index value, change the appropriate array value. Remember to add the parameters here as well.

```
onSelect(event, index) {
    // If you need to know which checkboxes are checked
    this.resultArray[index] = event.target.checked;
    // If you don't
    const result: EventTarget = event.target.checked;
    // Do something with value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of instances">
   <td><input type="checkbox" (click)='onSelect($event)'></td>
   <td>{{data["IP"]}}</td>
</tr>


onSelect(eventObject) {
    if (eventObject.target.checked) {
       // your logic here.
        console.log('checked', eventObject.target.checked);
       }
```

Hope, this would help you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
onSelect() {
    this.table_data = document.getElementById("just_a_table");
    for (var i=1, row; row = this.table_data.rows[i]; i++){
        for (var j=0, cell; cell = row.cells[j]; j++){
            if (cell[1].children[0].checked){
                console.log("It is checked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a proper angular solution. This is using vanilla JS. Using vanillaJS is not good practice on angular apps

Comment: @PatricioVargas, as a solution, this answer perfectly aids my issue. Could you please let us know what is the downside of using this solution?

Comment: @VigneshSP yes the solution works but it's not good practice to keep using vanilla js in an Angular app. That's why this frameworks came out, to write better and easier code. Also, he is using 2 for loops.  Most of the time using nested forloops is bad practice. By using 2 forloop you will make the browswer work harder. Using 2 forloops is  O(n^2) which will lead to perfomance issues. https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: @PatricioVargas, Thanks for the direction. I will go with the implementing the event method. Yes, I will make sure to go through the link provided to learn more. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem we are here to help. Remember to unmark this answer as the correct one since it can lead to more people making the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Try this,

Create a Boolean variable `public checkBoxValidate;`

And set value `false` for the variable in **ngOnInit()** `this.checkBoxValidate = false;`

```
 <table class="table table-hover" id="just_a_table">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th scope="col">Select</th>
           <th scope="col">IP Addr</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let data of instances">
           <td><input type="checkbox" (click)='onSelect()'></td>
           <td>{{data["IP"]}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**TS**

```
onSelect()
{
  if(this.checkBoxValidate == false)
  {
    this.checkBoxValidate = true;
  }
  else
  { 
    this.checkBoxValidate = false;
  }
}
```

**If this variable is true means, check box is checked else checkbox is unchecked**

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

On angular 2+, use like below:

```
<div class="togglebutton">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" [checked]="record.isStatus" (change)="changeStatus(record.id,$event)">
                                                <span class="toggle"></span>

                                            </label>
                                        </div>
```

On your ts file,

```
changeStatus(id, e) {
        var status = e.target.checked;
        this._companyHubService.addOrRemoveStatus(id, status).subscribe(result => {
            this.modalSave.emit();
            if (status)
                this.notify.success(this.l('AddedAsStatus'));
            else
                this.notify.success(this.l('RemovedFromStatus'));

        });
    }
```